# An analog of Mollweide's Formula for a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Note that as with [Mollweide's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide%27s_formula), this version for a cyclic quadrilateral not only relates the four sides to the four angles, but also includes the angle between the diagonals. It is not clear to me if this expression generalizes the Mollweide's Formulas or [Newton's Formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsFormulas.html) (which is my intention), so my question is: does the Mollweides's Formula (or Newton's version) follows from the relation in the image?[image]

Comment: Interesting question. However, rather than making people visit other sites just to understand what you're even talking about, please include the specific formulas of interest in the body of your question. Cheers!

Comment: @Blue, unfortunately I won't be able to do that for long, so if anyone can edit the question to make it clearer, please feel free to do so.

Comment: It really seems that this formula cannot be adapted to a triangle.

Comment: *"It really seems that this formula cannot be adapted to a triangle."* Actually, if you move $D$ to coincide to $C$, then the formula reduces to equation (3) on [Wolfram's "Newton's Formulas" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsFormulas.html) (with some labeling adjustments), so the identity does in fact generalize Newton.

Comment: I have never been so glad to be wrong. I love you Blue. This is another example of what the half angle formulas can do for us. The following link contains my proof of the -now confirmed- generalization. Link:https://geometriadominicana.blogspot.com/2022/01/generalization-of-mollweides-formulas.html?spref=fb&fbclid=IwAR2rSc65k1queRRQulY6S97Z1KLhwCoqv79B4fMzhkqPj2xd8DMuoU9xcno

Comment: A related question has been posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404991/generalization-of-the-law-of-tangents-for-a-cyclic-quadrilateral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anticipating reducing the formula to one of Newton's, rename elements of the figure as shown:

[image]

That is, angles $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ have been sub-divided into $\alpha+\alpha'$ and $\gamma+\gamma'$, and the segment labels have been scrambled: $a:=|BC|$, $b := |AD|$, $c:=|AB|$, $d:=|CD|$. Note that $\delta = \pi-\beta$ (as $\beta$ and $\delta$ are inscribed angles subtending opposing arcs). With these changes, the formula in question becomes

$$\frac{c+d}{a+b}\;\cot\frac12\theta = \frac{\sin\frac12(\alpha+\alpha'+\beta)}{\cos\frac12(\gamma+\gamma'-(\pi-\beta))} \to
\frac{c+d}{a+b}\;\cot\frac12\theta = \frac{\sin\frac12(\alpha+\alpha'+\beta)}{\sin\frac12(\gamma+\gamma'+\beta)} \tag{1}$$

Now, if we slide vertex $D$ along the circle to coincide with $C$ (so that $E$ does as well), we find that $\alpha'$ and $d$ shrink to nothing; $\gamma'$ and $\theta$ adjust to match $\beta$ and $\gamma$, respectively; and $\beta$ and $\delta$ don't change at all.

[image]

So, $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{c+0}{a+b}\;\cot\frac12\gamma = \frac{\sin\frac12(\alpha+0+\beta)}{\sin\frac12(\gamma+\beta+\beta)} \quad\to\quad
\frac{c}{a+b}\;\cot\frac12\gamma = \frac{\sin\frac12(\alpha+\beta)}{\sin\frac12(\gamma+2\beta)} \tag2$$

Since $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$, we have
$$\alpha+\beta=\pi-\gamma \qquad\qquad\gamma+2\beta = \pi-(\alpha-\beta)$$
whence $(2)$ becomes
$$\frac{c}{a+b}\;\frac{\cos\frac12\gamma}{\sin\frac12\gamma} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\frac12\gamma\right)}{\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\frac12(\alpha-\beta)\right)} = \frac{\cos\frac12\gamma}{\cos\frac12(\alpha-\beta)} \tag3$$
and we can write

> $$\frac{a+b}{c} = \frac{\cos\frac12(\alpha-\beta)}{\sin\frac12\gamma} \tag{$\star$}$$

which is formula $(3)$ on [MathWorld's "Newton's Formulas" entry](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsFormulas.html). $\square$